# Excel text special alignment

Tags: excel, alignment

I have the following lines contained in 6 contiguous cells (6 rows and **1 column**):

```
ich werde gereist sein  
du wirst gereist sein  
er wird gereist sein  
wir werden gereist sein  
ihr werdet gereist sein  
sie werden gereist sein
```

I would like to align the previous lines like this:

```
ich  werde   gereist  sein  
du   wirst   gereist  sein  
er   wird    gereist  sein  
wir  werden  gereist  sein  
irh  werdet  gereist  sein  
sie  werden  gereist  sein
```

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The most practical way *for your example* may be to switch (if necessary) to a non-proportional font (eg Courier New) and manually add spaces to suit. If you require this often or for very many cells then I would suggest VBA - but you have not tagged your question as such.

You might search for `du` and `er` and replace with `du#` and `er#` respectively, etc. (where the `#` here represents a space!) - then `ger eist` back to `gereist`.

Comment: VBA suggestions would be very appreciated too! (Sorry that I didn't mention VBA in my question, I thought the solution didn't require VBA).

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells whose internal alignment you wish to adjust and run this small macro:

```
Sub FixData()
    Dim mx As Long
    Selection.Font.Name = "Courier New"
    mx = 1
    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        ary = Split(v, " ")
        For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            If mx < Len(ary(i)) Then mx = Len(ary(i))
        Next i
    Next r

    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        ary = Split(v, " ")
        For i = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
            ary(i) = paddre(ary(i), mx)
        Next i
        r.Value = Join(ary, " ")
    Next r
End Sub



Public Function paddre(sIn, xTra As Long) As String
    paddre = sIn
    If Len(sIn) = xTra Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    While Len(paddre) <> xTra
        paddre = paddre & " "
    Wend
End Function
```